# Is it possible for a plugin to prevent certain plugins from being installed?

Tags: plugins, themes

Or perhaps if it can't prevent it, can the plugin disable certain plugins in the admin area and prevent them from being activated, sort of like the reverse of [disabling plugin deactivation](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-disable-plugin-deactivation-from-wordpress-admin-panel/)?

**Edit**: Changed the question from 'is it possible for a theme' to 'is it possible for a plugin'.

Comment: Can you add a specific example/use case? Themes can't stop a Plugin from being *activated*, but there are many ways to override/circumvent a Plugin's functionality, depending on the Plugin, and how it is implemented.

Comment: I'm thinking of a super opinionated theme where I want to prevent its users from installing popular but bad/outdated/basically non-recommended plugins.

Comment: That's not the job of a Theme. A Theme's purpose is entirely and only to display user content.

Comment: You are right. Say I move that functionality to a plugin instead?

Comment: Much better question. :) But we'd still need specific examples of Plugins to override, since there is no single, definitive answer.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, actually: is there a certain action I can use to deactivate another plugin (but apparently not, as you just said that there's no definite answer). Alternatively, is it possible to hide plugins from search result, or at the very least add a note to certain plugins on the search result and plugin admin page?

Answer (score 1):

Each plugin is registered by his main filename or directory.
That means that i can place woocommerce plugin (for example) in a dir called foo-bar and the woocommerce plugin will be registered as foo-bar (simplifying).

You can't detect it, so you can't avoid it to activate.
But, of course, you can do few tricks depending on the plugin you want to avoid.

Another example: if a plugin declares a well-known constant, you can detect this one and stop/remove the plugin. Of course, in case of update, the constant could be removed and.. broken.

Same way: disabling plugin deactivation is something that works graphically, you can't avoid the renaming of the plugin dir or the removal itself.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking that it probably can only be done with tricks some, depending on how the plugin is coded. Additionally, do you think it's possible to filter out certain plugins from search results in the Dashboard? Or maybe add some message on the result?

Comment: Since I can't edit my previous comment, I'm making a new comment. Assuming I don't want to get all fancy, and would be fine with detecting plugins by their default directory name, how do I get around to disable them?

Comment: Look at [this code](https://gist.github.com/mirkolofio/315f401f1d766fe03f26). That way you can build a self-hiding plugin when activated.

Comment: @mircobabini I know this question is a little old, but it appears the code you linked to has been removed. Do you have an updated code sample? Thanks.

Comment: Of course I do, check this up https://gist.github.com/mircobabini/315f401f1d766fe03f26